# MapStruct if source property is null use alternative property

Tags: java, mapstruct

Is there a simple way to conditionally use a different source property if the first property is null? I am looking for something like this:

```
@Mapping(target = "myTargetProperty", source = "mySourceProperty", alternativeWhenNull = "myAltSourceProperty")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`defaultValue`](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Mapping.html#defaultValue()) or [`defaultExpression`](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Mapping.html#defaultExpression()) to specify a value if the source property is null

For your specific use case you can use `defaultExpression = "java(source.getAlternativeProperty())`

Comment: hm in my specific case I'm running into what might be a mapstruct bug:

    `@Mapping(target = "myProp", source = "mySource2.myProp", defaultExpression = "java(mySource1.getMyProp())")
    MyTarget taskToTaak(MySource1 mySource1, MySource2 mySource2);`

generated code:

    `if ( mySource2 != null ) {
        if ( mySource2.getMyProp() != null ) {
            taak.setMyProp( taakConfig.getOmschrijving() );
        }
        else {
            mySource1.setMyProp( mySource1.getMyProp() );
        }
    }`